# Getting jert.jar, jnet.jar and jsse.jar?

Tags: java

I'm trying to setup jetty 7 with ssl, part of the instructions say:

**make sure that jcert.jar, jnet.jar and jsse.jar are on your classpath**

Where do we find those jars from? I'm running on mac 10.6. They don't seem to be part of my java installation, and not sure where to download them from otherwise,

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jsse.jar should be in

/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/CurrentJDK/Classes/jsse.jar

Suspect the others are around there somewhere perhaps with different names

Think the JSSE has been bundled with the JDK since 1.4

Answer (score 3):

You can find those jars into:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-java-plat-419418.html#jsse-1.0.3_04-fcs-do-oth-JPR

- Download:  JSSE 1.0.3 - Global for CDC 1.0.2 Final Release
- Extract the content and look into the path: 
  jsse-1_0_3_03-for-cdc-1_0_2-bin_samples-gl\jsse-1_0_3_03-for-cdc-1_0_2-gl\cdc_jsse1.0.3_03\lib

Regards